# Visual Basic -- Key List (Gamecontroller?)

Tags: vb6, key, gamecontroller

How can I find a specific value for Gamecontroller-Key?

I want to use them for a script in a game.

Example:

```
isKeyPressed(Settings.GetValueKey("Key", Keys.X))
```

Here are the only key-values I found:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa243025(v=vs.60).aspx

Comment: Game controllers don't emulate a keyboard. You will need to use the DirectShow or the WinMM joystick API to interface with the controller.

Answer (score 0):

If you wanna go that route, insted of using DirectShow or WinMM as Deanna suggested, you will need a keyboard emulator for your gamepad, here is a related question:

https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/13575/emulating-keyboard-and-mouse-commands-with-a-game-controller-control-pad-whi

If you need to get the event for the arrow keys on your app, make sure KeyPreview is True on Form Properties.

```
Private Sub Form_KeyDown(KeyCode As Integer, Shift As Integer)
    'On Error Resume Next
    Select Case KeyCode
        Case vbKeyUp
            MsgBox "Up"
        Case vbKeyDown
            MsgBox "Down"
        Case vbKeyLeft
            MsgBox "Left"
        Case vbKeyRight
            MsgBox "Right"
    End Select
End Sub
```

[Source](http://www.daniweb.com/software-development/visual-basic-4-5-6/threads/416489/how-to-use-arrow-keys-in-vb6-when-i-press-up-key-from-keyboard..-command-executes)